# Add \ to in a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, nvarchar

I need help in sql please.

I have a nvarchar field called Users in which i store strings like this:

UAT\dabrego

this is the query:

```
Select IdentityName from Users
```

Ans i want to retrive the strings like this:

UAT\\dabrego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select REPLACE(IdentityName, '\','\\') AS  IdentityName
from [Users]
```